# Caused by IllegalStateException

Tags: android, json, illegalstateexception, runtimeexception

I'm working on a project where I'm downloading and saving data from web to sqlite database. when I'm running my project its shows IllegalStateException (already close).

my logcat is:

```
    09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:266)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1081)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:574)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.irlsolutions.ittrading/databases/ITTrading.sqlite (conn# 0) already closed
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2134)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1526)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1508)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at com.irlsolutions.ittradinglibrary.Query_new.getItemFromEndOfDay(Query_new.java:89)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at com.irlsolutions.ittrading.Symbol_Fetcher.getSymbolFromLocal(Symbol_Fetcher.java:70)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at com.irlsolutions.ittrading.Markets$Markets_Thread.doInBackground(Markets.java:190)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at com.irlsolutions.ittrading.Markets$Markets_Thread.doInBackground(Markets.java:1)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:252)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

doInBackGround() is:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

    float flt_close1;
    float flt_close2;
    float variation;

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    xmlData = XML_Parser_Helper.parseXmlSax(Markets.this, "", R.raw.market_indices_america);        
    lst_codes = xmlData.getListOfItems();

    xmlData = XML_Parser_Helper.parseXmlSax(Markets.this, "", R.raw.market_indices_europe);
    lst_codes.addAll(xmlData.getListOfItems());

    xmlData = XML_Parser_Helper.parseXmlSax(Markets.this, "", R.raw.market_indices_asia);
    lst_codes.addAll(xmlData.getListOfItems());

    for(int i = 0; i < lst_codes.size(); i++){
    lst_symbols.add(
        symbolFetcher.getSymbolFromLocal(
            lst_codes.get(i).get("symbol_code").toString(), 
            lst_codes.get(i).get("market_code").toString(), 
            xmlData,
            "symbols",
            lst_codes.get(i).get("chain_code").toString()
        )
    );
    lst_symbols.get(i).put("company_name", lst_codes.get(i).get("company_name").toString());
    lst_symbols.get(i).put("symbol_code", lst_codes.get(i).get("symbol_code").toString());
    lst_symbols.get(i).put("market_code", lst_codes.get(i).get("market_code").toString());
    lst_symbols.get(i).put("chain_code", lst_codes.get(i).get("chain_code").toString());
    lst_symbols.get(i).put("flag", lst_codes.get(i).get("flag").toString());

    flt_close1 = (float)Double.parseDouble((lst_symbols.get(i).get("close_1").toString().equals(""))?"0.0":lst_symbols.get(i).get("close_1").toString());
    flt_close2 = (float)Double.parseDouble((lst_symbols.get(i).get("close_2").toString().equals(""))?"0.0":lst_symbols.get(i).get("close_2").toString());
    variation = Generic_Functions.getVariation(flt_close1, flt_close2);

    lst_symbols.get(i).put("variation", variation);

    if(symbolFetcher.isSymbolAddedToPortfolio(str_username, lst_codes.get(i).get("symbol_code").toString(), lst_codes.get(i).get("market_code").toString())){
        lst_symbols.get(i).put("added", true);
    }else{
        lst_symbols.get(i).put("added", false);
    }

    publishProgress(new Void[]{});
    }

    return null;
}
```

Function in which I'm using query:

```
    public HashMap<String,Object> getItemFromEndOfDay(String str_symbolCode,String str_marketCode){
        HashMap<String,Object> hm = new HashMap<String, Object>();          

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Init.TABLE_END_OF_DAY + " WHERE symbol_code='" + str_symbolCode + "' AND market_code='" + str_marketCode + "'", null);


        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            hm.put("symbol_code", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("symbol_code")));
            hm.put("market_code", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("market_code")));
            hm.put("instrument_name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("instrument_name")));
            hm.put("company_name", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("company_name")));
            hm.put("isin", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("isin")));
            hm.put("interval", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("interval")));
            hm.put("exchange", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("exchange")));
            hm.put("ex_open", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ex_open")));
            hm.put("ex_close", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ex_close")));
            hm.put("currency", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("currency")));
            hm.put("timezone", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("timezone")));

            hm.put("date_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date_1")));
            hm.put("hour_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hour_1")));
            hm.put("open_interest_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("open_interest_1")));
            hm.put("open_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("open_1")));
            hm.put("high_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("high_1")));
            hm.put("low_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("low_1")));
            hm.put("close_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("close_1")));
            hm.put("volume_1", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("volume_1")));

            hm.put("date_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date_2")));
            hm.put("hour_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("hour_2")));
            hm.put("open_interest_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("open_interest_2")));
            hm.put("open_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("open_2")));
            hm.put("high_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("high_2")));
            hm.put("low_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("low_2")));
            hm.put("close_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("close_2")));
            hm.put("volume_2", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("volume_2")));

            cursor.close();
            return hm;
        }else{
                hm.put("symbol_code", str_symbolCode);
            hm.put("market_code", str_marketCode);
            hm.put("instrument_name","");
            hm.put("company_name", "");
            hm.put("isin", "");
            hm.put("interval", "");
            hm.put("exchange", "");
            hm.put("ex_open", "");
            hm.put("ex_close", "");
            hm.put("currency", "");
            hm.put("timezone", "America/New_York");

            hm.put("date_1", "");
            hm.put("hour_1", "");
            hm.put("open_interest_1", "");
            hm.put("open_1", "");
            hm.put("high_1", "");
            hm.put("low_1", "");
            hm.put("close_1", "");
            hm.put("volume_1", "");

            hm.put("date_2", "-");
            hm.put("hour_2", "");
            hm.put("open_interest_2", "");
            hm.put("open_2", "");
            hm.put("high_2", "");
            hm.put("low_2", "");
            hm.put("close_2", "");
            hm.put("volume_2", "");

            cursor.close();
            return hm;
        }
//      cursor.close();
//      return hm;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't closing it twice, the issue is using it after it is close.

If you look at the query:

```
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.irlsolutions.ittrading/databases/ITTrading.sqlite (conn# 0) already closed
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2134)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1526)
09-29 12:14:49.485: E/AndroidRuntime(4956):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1508)
```

You see it comes from `rawquery`, a  function you use in the beginning of that `getItemFromEndOfDay`. So if I'm not mistaken, you get this error in the *beginning* of calling the function, because the database isn't open at that point. You could easily verify this by checking how far in the code you're getting.

Make sure you do not close anything and then try to use the database for a second time. Add some debug lines to verify it is indeed this line, and if you've closed anything before that.

Comment: and do you call that function twice maybe? You really should add some logging / do some debugging as to WHEN this error pops up.

Comment: Yeah, that's what it looks like. We could do with seeing the rest of the code

Answer (score 1):

The exception indicates that you're calling close when the cursor is already closed.
The line number in the exception will tell you where; at a guess I'd say it was in the else block

Comment: but when i remove cursor.close from else & if block...and used it out of if condition..it shows same problem

Comment: i have already done with close after if..but not working..& also opened the database where I'm calling it.